# how to use C function in C# when one of the parameters is void*?

Tags: c#, c

I have a C code that does the following function:

```
int Read (DWORD Address, DWORD NoOfBytes, int UnitSize, void* Buffer);
```

when the buffer is being filled with data from the address. the functions' return value is 1 or 0 stating success or failure.

the code in C# that I tried to do is:

```
private const string LibName = "Test.dll";
   [DllImport(LibName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
            public static extern int Read([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4), In] int Address, int NoOfBytes, 
                int UnitSize, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny), Out] Object Buffer);
```

I use this function in the following way:

```
var resultBuf = new short[40];
int returnValue = Read(parsedAddress, size, 2, resultBuf);
```

but the result is that the buffer remains a buffer of 40 zeros.

any idea how to get this work? what an I doing wrong??

more details:
the C function works perfectly.
the strangest thing that happens is that on C# I get the response instead of in the buffer- but in the returned value (instead of returning 0 or 1 it returns the value as int)

Comment: what is `size`in call  `Read(parsedAddress, size, 2, resultBuf);`? and also why unitSize is `2`.?

Comment: size is an int that holds the size of bytes I want to read , unitSize the unit size access that will be used (1-BYTE, 2-WORD, 4-DWORD)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you should be using IntPtr when using DLL interop. Best of all, you won`t even need the "out" parameter. :)

You can of course use for instance byte* instead of void* if you plan to use the function only on byte arrays or so, but the previous method should be used instead.

```
public static extern int Read(uint Address, uint NoOfBytes, int UnitSize, IntPtr buffer)
```

This should do it just fine.

Also keep in mind that DLL imports are a costly operation and should be avoided, for instance, a "read" operation could be implemented in unsafe code in pure C#, and would probably perform better (although the difference can be considered negligibly minuscule in cases like this).

Comment: I get a compilation error using this code: Argument 4: cannot convert from 'short[]' to 'System.IntPtr'

Comment: It`s because you need to create that IntPtr. convert to (fixed short * p = resultBuf) { IntPtr resultPtr = (IntPtr)p; /* your code here */ } Obviously you compile in unsafe mode.

Comment: First you cast your short[] to short* with (fixed short * p = resultBuf), then cast your short* (p) to IntPtr, which is resultPtr. ResultPtr will point to the address of resultBuf.

Comment: Ok, it compiled but it didn't work..  short[] resultBuf = new short[10];
                fixed (short* p = resultBuf)
                {
                    IntPtr resultPtr = (IntPtr)p;
                    returnValue = Read(parsedAddress, size, 2, resultPtr);
                }

Comment: did you get to see this that I wrote above? "more details: the C function works perfectly. the strangest thing that happens is that on C# I get the response instead of in the buffer- but in the returned value (instead of returning 0 or 1 it returns the value as int)"

Comment: The most probable cause of your error is the size. An Int ptr has a base size of 4 bytes, so it increments with 4 bytes. I`d rewrite the C function to use byte* instead of void, then you can lose the IntPtr from the C# side and work directly with a byte[] array.